# Virtualbox Ubuntu NAT - one VM has internet, other does not

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, nat

I have one VM that is provided to me.
It has NAT and Host-Only-Adapter enabled; it has internet access.

I've installed two new VMs: Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.

In both cases, I enabled NAT but there was no internet access from the beginning.

How do I determine which settings enable the first VM to have internet with NAT?

Comment: Is the NAT subnet of your first machine the same as the NAT subnet of the later machines? Try resetting NAT in VBOX.

Comment: @John how do I check that?

Comment: Here is a good article on VBOX networking including NAT.    ...  https://www.nakivo.com/blog/virtualbox-network-setting-guide/

Comment: @John that doesn't help me.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your machines and not with Virtual Box.   Make another new machine and see if it works correctly using NAT.

Comment: @John I stated I made two new VMs - Ubuntu 18 and 20 - and I have same issue.

Comment: Make sure your machines are safely stored, uninstall Virtual Box, restart, install the newest version of Virtual Box, then try again with connection.

Comment: @John I will but the fact that ONE VM works - from my IT - makes me think the guest OS is modified (via script) to change the networking.

Comment: @John I did the steps and installed new Ubuntu 20 but NAT still not working. My original VM still has internet on NAT.

Comment: @John working VM: `default route is 10.0.3.2`. Broken VM: `default route is 10.0.2.2`. Is that relevant?

Comment: I am out of ideas. I have been using virtual machines for years and I have not seen this issue except for what I have suggested

Comment: @John is the default route difference meaningful?

Comment: On my machines, standard NAT and standard Bridged networking work fine.

Comment: @John what settings can I compare inside guest OS that could make one work and one not?

Comment: Try resetting your network settings inside the non working machine . That might help.